# Can I colorize text in a TextFormField?

Tags: flutter, dart

I know how to colorize label text in Flutter with rich text, but is it possible to do that for user-entered text in a TextFormField? (Note: I'm talking about multiple colors in the same field, so this is not just the text style).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to have multiple text colors within one text field?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about this, but I think you can use a rich text editor.

First, install the [`flutter_quill`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill) package.

Then, try the following code:

```
final QuillController quillController = QuillController.basic();
```

---

```
QuillToolbar.basic(
  controller: quillController,
),
const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
Expanded(
  child: Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
      border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
    ),
    child: QuillEditor.basic(
      controller: quillController,
      readOnly: false,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting idea. It looks like it doesn't work on web yet, so probably not something I can use (yet), but good to know it exists. In the meantime, I have come up with an alternative UX for my problem. I'll leave the question open as I think its an interesting one I'd like to know solutions to anyway.

Comment: Hi @GrahamWheeler what do you mean by "doesn't work on web yet"?